# jqTree - css to show dotted lines in tree

Tags: css, treeview

Does anyone have some css styles and images to apply to jqTree to show the outline of the tree?  Something like YUI treeview that shows a dotted border

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/treeview/default_tree.html

Answer (score 0):

Turns out YUI treeview allows you to use existing html to render.

```
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/tree.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

    <!-- Required CSS -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/treeview/assets/skins/sam/treeview.css">

    <!-- Dependency source file --> 
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js" ></script>
    <!-- Optional dependency source file to decode contents of yuiConfig markup attribute--> 
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/json/json-min.js" ></script>

<!-- TreeView source file --> 
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/treeview/treeview-min.js" ></script>

<script>
      var tree;
        function treeInit() {
            tree = new YAHOO.widget.TreeView("committeeTree");
            // if required, add nodes here
            tree.render();
        }

        $(function () {
              $("#myTree").tree({
                    data: source
                });

              treeInit();

        });

</script>
```